# Clicked View Designer on a WinForm. Why was the file auto Checked out from Source Control?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vss, winforms

When I click "View Designer" to view a Winform in Design mode, VS2010 automatically checks out the file.

I realize that there are probably options to silently check out the file without connfirmation, but why is VS thinking that it needs the file checked out in the first place? If I don't check it out, I can't view it. T

[Screen Capture](http://screencast.com/t/YzQ2NjM3YT)

Answer (score 2):

Have you double checked that there haven't been any changes made to the file?

Another possibility is that you have a component that performing some action which requires edit access to the file. I have a form with a `TableLayoutPanel` that does this. Viewing the code seems to force a recalculation of the layout panel even though nothing moves.

Comment: I did a before and after compare  and nothing changed. You're theory is a good one. In any event, someone screwed up. It could be a 3rd party vendor for my form.

Comment: I mean to put this question on Stack Overflow. I'm surprised that there are Visual Studio Tags here